# i18Next React Native enum translation issue

Tags: typescript, react-native, enums, translation, i18next

Passing the t on the enum value is not working it givings an error.

```
 enum catSize {
    SMALL = 'Small', //works
    MEDIUM = 'Medium', //works
    LARGE = 'Large', //works
}

enum catSize {
    SMALL = t('sizes.small'), //error
    MEDIUM = t('sizes.medium'), //error
    LARGE = t('sizes.large'),
}
```

Gives the following error:
Computed values are not permitted in an enum with string valued members.ts(2553)

Comment: enum is a typescript construct (not evaluated at runtime)... the t function is a javascript function called at runtime

Comment: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/479